# PSAD / removed iptables block

Tags: security, iptables, psad

I'm pretty new to PSAD but eagerly getting into it to have a safer installation. But some understanding is missing

I've had yesterday the following notification :

```
[psad-status] removed iptables block against xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

It was an automatic notification, my problem right here is that there is no particular reason that I understand so far that would white-list automatically an IP

This is quite a problem as I'd like to rely on a strict behaviour, but without understanding well what happened, can't be sure about it. Nothing accurate found googling about this specific one

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

It didn't *whitelist* that IP, it merely unblacklisted it.  Presumably it did so because a previous time-based block expired.  The documentation, or more detailed logging, may provide you with more information about exactly what happened in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

That message is caused by an address being removed from the blacklist because it has reached the  timeout limit.

> AUTO_BLOCK_TIMEOUT
>
> Defines the length of time that an auto-generated block rule will remain in effect (ENABLE_AUTO_IDS must be set to "Y" for this keyword to be used). The default is "3600" seconds (one hour).